# cannot create a custom list using hasmap

Tags: android, adapter

```
package com.thesoft.smsdemo;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.R.integer;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.thesoft.smsdemo.JSONParser;

public class Upload extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_upload);
        new Hi().execute();

    }


    private class Hi extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        ProgressDialog rDialog;
        JSONParser lv = new JSONParser();
        ListView vti ;
        public  HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> notes_data = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();


        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            rDialog = new ProgressDialog(Upload.this);
            rDialog.setMessage("Fetching Data From Server..");
            rDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            rDialog.setCancelable(false);
            rDialog.show();


        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... sam) {


            List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

            params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("co_name", "All"));

            return lv.makeHttpRequest(
                            "+++++URL Link++++++++",
                            "GET", params);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {


            Log.d("value", result);

            String name = "", head = "", desb = "", date = "";
            JSONArray jsArray;
            try {

                jsArray = new JSONArray(result);
                Log.d("json arry", "" + jsArray.length());
                for (int j = 0; j < jsArray.length(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> data = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    JSONObject jobj = jsArray.getJSONObject(j);
                    data.put("co_name", jobj.getString("co_name").toString());
                    data.put("head", jobj.getString("head").toString());
                    data.put("desb", jobj.getString("desb").toString());
                    data.put("date", jobj.getString("date").toString());
                    Log.d("valuesss",j+"");
                    notes_data.put(j, data);
                    Log.d("name",jobj.getString("co_name").toString());
                    Log.d("name",jobj.getString("head").toString());
                    Log.d("name",jobj.getString("date").toString());

                }

                /*String[] notes_da = {"hjhkh","hggg","hghgghgh"};
                for (int i = 0; i < notes_da.length; i++) {
                    notes_da[i] = "Notes " + i;
                    }*/

                MySimpleArrayAdapter mr = new MySimpleArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), notes_data);
/*              ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),R.layout.custom_list, R.id.tv, notes_da);
*/              vti=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.li1);
                vti.setAdapter(mr);
            } catch (JSONException e) {


                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {

                rDialog.dismiss();


                Log.d("valuesss",notes_data.get(3).get("head"));
            }

        }

    }

    public class MySimpleArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
        private final Context context;

        HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> data = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>>();

        public MySimpleArrayAdapter(Context context, HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, String>> data) {
            super(context, R.layout.custom_list);
            this.context = context;
            this.data = data;
        }

        @SuppressLint("ViewHolder")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
            TextView des = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.t2);
            TextView date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            // change the icon for Windows and iPhone
            String head = data.get(position).get("head");
            String desb = data.get(position).get("desb");
            String date1 = data.get(position).get("date");

            textView.setText(head);
            des.setText(desb);
            date.setText(date1);


            return convertView;
        }

    }
    }
```

**The data is fetched but not able to set it on custom Adapter for Listview
the data can be seen in log cat but the list activity is not shown on the device. Please Help me with this code Thanks**

The data is fetched but not able to set it on custom Adapter for Listview
the data can be seen in log cat but the list activity is not shown on the device. Please Help me with this code Thanks

Comment: is there any error log you get ? post your  activity_upload xml.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you are missing:

1. Inside getView(...)
   convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, parent);
   It should be inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_list, null);

   @param root Optional view to be the parent of the generated hierarchy.
   public View inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root)
2. You have to override getCount in your custom adapter
   @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return data.size();
   }

   where data = new HashMap>();
   Additionally, its better to reuse cells in getView of your custom adapter. For this purpose you could use ViewHolder.

If not helpful, please share your layout xmls.